# DOM parsing a document: adding and removing comma based on condition

Tags: python

I am using Python's [pattern.web](http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/pattern-web) module to perform some basic web mining tasks. I am trying to extract only first 15 keywords and append each keyword with a comma `","`. So, my resulting file contains a list of keywords that looks like:

```
scallops, scallop shells, sea scallops, scallop shell, how to cook scallops, scallop shells for sale, frozen scallops, fresh scallops, dry scallops, cooking scallops, baptism shell, scallop recipe, large scallop shells, diver scallops, bay scallops,
```

Now, I do not want the comma `","` after the 15th/last keyword `"bay scallops,"`
I need a little help to modify my code below so that at the 15th iteration the code doesn't add the comma. If it were a simple for loop iterating an array, I could use `iteritems()` to extract key and value and add an if condition, but here I cannot figure out how to do it.

```
from pattern.web import URL, DOM, plaintext, extension

folder = '../some_folder'

dom = DOM(content)
print "traversing ... "
for e in dom('td.spgb-f')[:15]:
    for a in e('span.sptc-e'):
        File = open(os.path.join(folder, "meta_keywords.html"), mode="a")
        print ('adding %s' %(plaintext(a.content)))
        File.write(plaintext(a.content) + ", ")
        File.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of thinking about appending a comma (your separator) on every iteration, consider it the other way round as pre-pending a separator that starts off as blank and is then set as your comma value at the end of the first iteration of your loop.

```
separator=''
for e in dom('td.spgb-f')[:15]:
    for a in e('span.sptc-e'):
        ...
        print (separator + 'adding %s' %(plaintext(a.content)))
        separator = ', '
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your answer before I posted. Mine is essentially the same. :)

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend Lauro's answer, but in some cases such a list might not fit in memory and a "streaming" approach is better.

Then you can try this instead:

```
first = True
file = open(...)
for a in e('span.sptc-e'):
    if not first:
        file.write(", ")
    file.write(plaintext(a.content) + ", ")
    first = False
file.close()
```

You keep opening and closing the file, which is not necessary. You can open it before your loop, then closing it when you are done. The best way of doing this is often to use a `with' block:

```
with open(...) as file:
    file.write(...)
# The file is automatically closed after the block
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing each individual string to the file you can add them to a list, without the comma, and use `", ".join(your_list_here)` to create the string that will be written to the file. The `join` method takes care of placing the comma just between the elements.